# Help killing off Process for Mem Leak

Tags: bash, shell-script, android

I am currently building an Android LP kernel, and have some pretty sweet tweaks already running and built into it.

I know there are numerous LP memory leaks (i've already got the bootanimation one patched up)

What I'm wondering is, if there is a way I can check for processes causing a memory leak, and if found, kill the process.

So, I have crond setup already and runs just like it would on a linux box, bash binary as well

```
FREEMEM=$(free | awk 'FNR == 3 {print $4/($3+$4)*100}');
```

Gets me the available memory left, is there a way to use this to snag the process causing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closest you'll get is with `ps aux`.  This will show you the number of virtual pages allocated to a program.  Whether these pages are actually used, you won't know unless you profile every running process.  These numbers should be good enough for finding a leak, though